# What does this symbol "‰" mean in metabolic studies.

Tags: notation

Have a look at this article and you can understand the research area.
Jahren, A.H., Kraft, R.A., 2008. Carbon and nitrogen stable isotopes in fast food: Signatures of corn and confinement. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 105, 17855–17860.. doi:10.1073/pnas.0809870105

Relates to change in 13C concentration in breath, related to diet.  I could'nt see where to post the question, none of the google searches ever bothered to explain that symbol.
GOOD ANSWER - THANKS

Comment: It means "per mille" or something equivalent in Latin - i.e. per thousand, whereas $\%$ is "per cent" - per hundred

Comment: [Wikipedia page on per mille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mille)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wonder if this is really related to MSE!

Answer (score 1):

per thousand or per mille, mainly used in chemistry

Comment: This answer could be improved by giving a reference.